# Proving by induction $P_n \le 5 - \frac5n$

Tags: induction

for $n\ge1$ let:$$P_n = (\frac21).(\frac54).(\frac{10}9).(\frac{17}{16})...(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}) = \prod^n_{k=1}(\frac{k^2+1}{k^2}). $$
Prove by induction  for $n\ge 2$: $$P_n \le 5 -\frac5n $$
I did ask a variation of this question before, the answers did help somewhat, but I still have trouble. So here is where I am stuck and don't know what to do:
**Basis Step:** Let $n = 2,$ then $$P_2 = \frac52 \ \le 5-\frac54 =\frac52$$  $$\frac52\le\frac52$$ is true.
**Inductive Step:** assume for $k\ge2$ $$P_k \le5-\frac5k$$  Need to prove that: $$P_{k+1} \le5-\frac{5}{k+1}$$Or $$P_{k+1} =P_k(\frac{(k+1)^2+1}{(k+1)^2})\le5-\frac{5}{k+1}$$So this is where I am stuck.  I don't know how to prove it from here. The suggestion from here on didn't make sense to me (which was to replace $P_k$ with $5-\frac5k.)$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, $P_2=\frac 21 \cdot \frac 54 = \frac 52 \le \frac 52$.  You lost the leading factor $\frac 21$ but it still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that
$P_k \le 5 -\frac{5}{k}$.

So $P_{k+1}
=P_k(\frac{(k+1)^2+1}{(k+1)^2})
\le (5 -\frac{5}{k})(1+\frac1{(k+1)^2})
= 5(1-\frac1{k})(1+\frac1{(k+1)^2})
$
and you want this to be
$\le 5(1-\frac1{k+1})$.

This is the same as ahowing
$(1-\frac1{k})(1+\frac1{(k+1)^2})
\le 1-\frac1{k+1}
$

or
$1-\frac1{k}+\frac1{(k+1)^2}-\frac1{k(k+1)^2}
\le1-\frac1{k+1}
$

or
$\frac1{(k+1)^2}-\frac1{k(k+1)^2}
\le \frac1{k}-\frac1{k+1}
$

or
$\frac1{(k+1)^2}-\frac1{k(k+1)^2}
\le \frac1{k(k+1)}
$

which is clearly true since
$\frac1{(k+1)^2}
\le \frac1{k(k+1)}
$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To prove
$$
P_k(\frac{(k+1)^2+1}{(k+1)^2})\le5-\frac{5}{k+1}
$$
it is enough to prove
$$
(5-\frac{5}{k})(\frac{(k+1)^2+1}{(k+1)^2})\le5-\frac{5}{k+1}.
$$
Simplify this expression, and you will obtain what is required.